# asp.net cookie is not getting updated

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net, cookies

I am trying to update cookie like this

```
 Response.Cookies["cat"].Value =HttpUtility.UrlEncode( "autos");
```

But for some reason my cookie value is not getting updated

I have also tried using writing cookie using jquery like this

```
 Page.RegisterStartupScript("cook", "<script>$.cookie('cat','autos')</script>");
```

But I am clueless why my cookie not getting updated

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Do you get NullRefferenceException when trying to set value of cookie that is not there?

Comment: not getting any exception

Comment: Did you use Fiddler (or any other HTTP debugger) to check if response actually contains cookie?

Comment: I can set the cookie from javascript and its working fine. But unable to set it from server c# code

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the cookie expiry date

```
cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.Add(TimeSpan.FromHours(CookieTimeOutHours));
```

Answer (score 0):

I was setting cookie on selected index change event of radio button list. And radio button list was autopost back. And in selected index change event I was redirecting to other page.

So that's why the server side code was not able to save cookie on client side bc the page never rendered due to redirection.

So I instead set cookie on client side. Problem solved